# Parallel write on a file opened "by block"

Tags: python, multithreading, unix

I know that if two concurrent processes wants to write to the same file, the first come locks the file for write, so the second must wait until the lock is released.

Now, I have N files named block_i, with i = 1..N, of 1 Gb each. I need to create a large file block_all, of size N Gb, composed by each block_i file.
Since each block_i must be written exactly in bytes

```
((i-1) * 2**30) --- ((i * 2**30) - 1)
```

of the block_all file, is there a way to write all N files in true parallel since there will never be overlaps? I.e. is there a way to lock a file for write BY BLOCK?

Note: I am on a unix os and I am working in python.

Thank you

Comment: I would think that that task is IO bound i.e. you would not get a speedup if you try to write in parallel because the disk itself can't write in parallel (ofcourse only if it really can't, if it is a raid setup it might be able to write in parallel, but I would have thought that the OS handles that and you don't need to write in parallel).

Comment: You are absolutely right, I forgot to mention that there are several disks (8 or 16) mounted as a single logical volume with lvm, so I'd like to exploit the fact that these disks could actually write in parallel